# PHP zip_entry_read Failed to Show The Image

Tags: php, zip

I have a zip file "test.zip" which contain many files and a picture called "dp.bmp". So i use below script to search and show that picture file. But unfortunately, the pic could'nt display correctly.

The image only show horizontal line of picture (not showing whole picture as it's height and width), like below pic :

[image]

Then i tried to modify the line :

```
echo '<img width="700" height="700" src="data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode($contents).'"/>';
```

But still only show horizontal line of that picture

Here is my original source code :

```
            <?php
            $zip = zip_open("test.zip");

            if ($zip)
              {
              while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
                {
                if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry))
                  {
                  $expFile =  explode("/",zip_entry_name($zip_entry));
                      if ($expFile[1] == "dp.bmp" ) {
                          $contents = zip_entry_read($zip_entry);
                          echo '<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode($contents).'" />';
                          zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                        }
                    }
                }

                zip_close($zip);
                }
            ?>
```

I also test with other picture file and format such as JPG, but still couldn't show whole pic.

Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP Manual, zip_open: Some older PHP versions used to return false if zip_open failed, and newer versions return the number of error (as integer), so instead of this:

```
$zip = zip_open("test.zip");
if ($zip){
}
```

used this:

```
$zip = zip_open("test.zip");
if (is_resource($zip)) {

}
```

Comment: thanks tess for additional info. But still didn't solve the problem. Any other solution ?

Comment: try to add id or class for display your element:echo '<img class="zip_img" src="data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode($contents).'"/>'; and add some css attribute like position: absolute; display: inline-block to see if it could show correctly, it might be not php issue but client side css issue instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to decelerate size of unpacked file

```
zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry))
```